# Angular 2 writing structural directive like ngFor, iterableDiffer may be causing errors

Tags: javascript, angular2-directives, ngfor, ng-template

Hello I am fairly new to Angular 2, and wanted to write an implementation of ngFor to practice. I found this tutorial:
 https://teropa.info/blog/2016/03/06/writing-an-angular-2-template-directive.html

I had it working, but recently I keep getting this error. "ERROR TypeError: this._trackByFn is not a function".

I wish could debug this more but the documentation is very little, and I don't completely understand the IterableDiffer(s). All see it's dieing  after line 41. I've been trying to figure out what I change for several hours now.

```
let changes = this.differ.diff(this.collection);
```

Here is the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/aM8Wdz72gu7BVNAN9Ulv?p=preview

Thanks for any help offered.

**UPDATE:**

I found out that I can get my directive to work if I run it in Angular 2, and take out the typing of differ, like this:
`private differ:IterableDiffer`(now)
`private differ:IterableDiffer<any>`(before)

Still not a solution because I would like to figure out how I can make this work in Angular 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is upstream of the point where you diff the collection. Angular 4 removed the ChangeDetectorRef parameter for the IterableDifferFactory. I would suggest going back to your Angular 4 version and changing the line of code where you get your differ from something like:

```
this.differ = this.differs.find(coll).create(this.changeDetector);
```

to something like:

```
this.differ = this.differs.find(coll).create((value) => value);
```

I made that change on my custom version of ngFor and that allowed it to work in Angular 4.